# Tree complexity and gamma parameter in xgboost

Tags: xgboost, loss-function, gradient-boosting-decision-trees

According to [xgboost](https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/2939672.2939785) paper, regularization is given by:

$$\Omega(f) = \gamma T + \lambda || w||^2$$

where $\gamma$ is the complexity of a tree (i.e., number of leaves in the tree).

The parameter `gamma` in xgboost library, on the other hand, controls the minimum split at a node in order to proceed. Hence, is the $\gamma$ in the equation above used by xgboost software package? I could not find any reference to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the paragraph following equation (1):

> $T$ is the number of leaves in the tree.

$\gamma$ is a hyperparameter that affects how much regularization occurs on the size (number of leaves) of the tree.

Now it turns out that you can interpret $\gamma$ (at least roughly, see note at bottom) as ([[source]](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/parameter.html#parameters-for-tree-booster)):

> Minimum loss reduction required to make a further partition on a leaf node of the tree. The larger gamma is, the more conservative the algorithm will be.

You can see that from equation (2), the regularized objective:

$$\mathcal{L}(\phi) = \sum_i l(\hat{y}_i, y_i) + \sum_k \Omega(f_k),\\
\text{where }\Omega(f)=\gamma T + \frac12 \lambda \|w\|^2.$$

By making the split, you increase $T$ by one, so the penalty increases by $\gamma$, and so your base loss term $l$ needs to decrease by at least $\gamma$ for this to be an overall improvement.  **Note:** Of course, this ignores what happens to the leaf weights $w$ in splitting one node into two.