# Gamma parameter in xgboost

Tags: machine-learning, xgboost

As per the original paper on xgboost, the best split at a node is found by maximising the quantity below

$
\cal{L}_{\rm split} =  \frac{1}{2} \sum \left [ \frac{G_L}{H_L + \lambda} + \frac{G_R}{H_R + \lambda} - \frac{G_I}{H_I + \lambda} \right ] - \gamma
$

There exists a gamma parameter in xgboost package; assuming it is referring to the same parameter as in the equation, why would it impact the choice of the split if its value does not change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that it does not affect the choice of *which* split to make.  Instead, it affects the choice of *whether* to make any split.  If every $\mathcal{L}_{\text{split}}$ is negative, then **no** split will be made at the node, pre-pruning the tree.

See also [Tree complexity in xgboost](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/94025/55122)